# Mutually exclusive events and probabilities.

Tags: probability

This is a question set in my maths class and I think it has a trick question. It's super simple, probably far too simple for this website, but here goes anyway.

> Assume that we have two events, $A$ and $B$, that are independent and mutually exclusive. Assume further that we have $P(A)=0.1$ and $P(B)=0.1$. What is $P(A \cap B)$?

I am thinking the answer is $0$, as if the events are mutually exclusive they should never happen at the same time.

The reason I am stuck is the teacher has said the answer is $0.1 \times 0.1$.

Another small point:

Question

If I have a fair coin and I toss it 3 times then I think the sample space is?

{HHH, HHT, HTT, HTH, TTT, TTH, THH, THT}?

Am I correct and if not why not?

I do think they are correct but I would just like to double check?

Comment: it is not possible for two events to be independent and mutually exclusive (excluding cases where one or the other of the events has probability $0$).

Comment: what about if I removed the independent part from the question?

Comment: If you just assume they are mutually exclusive then, by definition, $P(A\cap B)=0$.  If you just assume they are independent then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$.

Comment: perfect, I should speak to my teacher about this.

Comment: For the small point are they correct. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Yes, those are the possible outcomes from three tosses of a coin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. If two events are mutually exclusive, it means that they cannot happen at the same time (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity)). This means that $A\cap B=\varnothing$ and $P(A\cap B)=0$.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!